# nodejs + socket.io + azure. continuous polling issue

Tags: node.js, azure, websocket, socket.io

I am facing some problem with socket getting keep polled continuously without gap. Not sure whats happening.

If same code placed in digital ocean cloud, it's not happening.

Little background:

I'm running azure VM behind load balancers.

[image]

Comment: Surely with the enormous amount of information provided you'll get answers... Nevertheless, the issue is probably that the load balancers don't support web sockets and socket.io is thus falling back to long polling.

Answer (score 0):

If you created load balancer using *Application Request Routing* with IIS, you'd need to [Disable WebSocket when using socket.io on node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support#issues).

> If you are using the WebSocket support in socket.io on node.js in your
>   site, you will need to disable the default IIS WebSockets module by
>   adding the below snippet to your `web.config` or `applicationHost.config`.
>   If this is not done, the IIS WebSockets module will attempt to handle
>   the WebSocket communication rather than letting this task fall through
>   to node.js (and hence your application). This will result in
>   unexpected errors when you attempt to access your site.
>
> ```
> <system.webServer>
>     ...
>     <webSocket enabled="false"/>
> </system.webServer>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Updating to latest socket library in nodeJS fixed this issue. Try your luck!